# Lesser known derivations of well-known formulas and theorems

Tags: alternative-proof

What are some lesser known derivations of well-known formulas and theorems?

I ask because I recently found a new way to derive the quadratic formula which didn't involve completing the square as is commonly taught. Doing so I was wondering what other proofs and derivations for other formulas that have remained unknown to most people?
Whether it be because the proof is too complex or less pretty, I still find it insightful to see different ways to solve a problem. To me it makes me understand  proofs better, and thus also giving a better comprehension of it.

> $$
> \begin{align}
> &\text{Given a quadratic function } f:\\[0.1em]
> f &=ax^2+bx+c = a(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = ax^2-a(r_1+r_2)+ar_1r_2\\[0.1em]
> a &= a,\enspace \frac{b}{a} = -(r_1+r_2),\enspace \frac{c}{a} = r_1r_2\\[1em]
> f' &= 2ax+b, \enspace f'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow x = -\frac{b}{2a}\\[0.2em]
> \text{This is an}& \text{ extremum of } f \text{, and is equidistant from each root } r_1, \enspace r_2 \text{ as shown:}\\[0.4em]
> \frac{b}{a} &= -(r_1+r_2) \iff -\frac{b}{2a} = \frac{r_1+r_2}{2} \\[1em]
> \Rightarrow \enspace &\text{The roots are of the form } r= -\frac{b}{2a}\pm d\\[1em]
> \frac{c}{a} = r_1r_2 &= (-\frac{b}{2a}+d)(-\frac{b}{2a}-d) = \frac{b^2}{4a^2}-d^2\\[0.2em]
> \Rightarrow\enspace& d^2 = \frac{b^2}{4a^2}-\frac{c}{a} = \frac{b^2}{4a^2}-\frac{4ac}{4a^2} = \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}\\[0.2em]
> \Rightarrow\enspace&d = \pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\\[1em]
> \text{Which yields }& r = -\frac{b}{2a}\pm d = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\enspace\square
> \end{align}
> $$

Comment: I really like this derivation personally. Its very nicely geometrically motivated

Comment: You may find [these 100 proofs of Pythagorean Theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/index.shtml) interesting

Comment: I love this derivation, but it's worth noting that it's basically completing the square in disguise: shifting your extremum to zero is exactly equivalent to putting the quadratic in the form $s^2-t$, where $s=x+(b/2a)$.

Answer (score 8):

The part of [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) which states that $(p-1)!\equiv -1 {\mod p}$ for any prime $p$ is normally proved by grouping elements in the product $(p-1)!$ with their inverses, but it also admits a proof using Sylow theory by first showing that there are $(p-2)!$ Sylow $p$-subgroups of $S_p$. To do this, observe first that a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_p$ is generated by a permutation of $p$ objects, of order $ p $. There are $(p-1)!$ of these, and each subgroup is isomorphic to a cyclic group with $p$ elements, which has $p-1$ generators.

By the third Sylow theorem, we then have $(p-2)!\equiv 1 {\mod p}$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 7):

In 1955, Hillel Furstenberg gave a ***topological*** proof for the fact that there are infinitely many prime numbers which derives a contradiction by observing that if there were only finitely many, a certain set would be closed that from topological arguments is known not to be closed.

The full proof can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg's_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes).

Comment: I wouldn't say that's a topological proof; there isn't any actual topology used besides the definition of a topology on a space (and the definition is nothing more than convenient nomenclature or bookkeeping). It's still a cool proof, though.

Comment: Here is a version of Fuerstenberg's proof: We are arguing about periodic sets of integers. The set $N_p$ of all integers prime to $p$ is periodic, and the intersection of two periodic sets is periodic. If there were only finitely many primes the set $\{1,-1\}$ would be periodic.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a proof due to Zagier that every prime $p = 4n + 1$ is the sum of two squares: On the finite set $A = \{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}:\, p = x^2 + 4yz\}$, define
$$f(x, y, z) = \begin{cases}
(x + 2z, z, y - x - z) & \text{if $x < y - z$}; \\
(2y - x, y, x - y + z) & \text{if $y - z < x < 2y$}; \\
(x - 2y, x -y + z, y)  & \text{if $x > 2y$}.
\end{cases}$$
The function $f$ has exactly one fixed point: $(1, 1, n)$. Any involution $g$ of $A$ (i.e., function with $g = g^{-1}$) must have a number of fixed points $F_g$ equal to $\#A \pmod{2}$, since $\frac{1}{2}\left(F_g + \#A\right)$ is an integer by Burnside's theorem. (Specifically, it's the number of orbits of $A$ under $g$). Thus the involution $(x, y, z) \to (x, z, y)$ must have also have an odd number of fixed points; in particular, there must exist at least one fixed point $(a, b, b)\in A$. Thus $p = a^2 + (2b)^2$, as required.

Comment: This is Zagier's famous "one-sentence proof."

Comment: I elaborated on some of the details that would ordinarily be omitted in a research paper, but there is something to be said for a one-sentence proof of a nontrivial result.

Answer (score 2):

The [Cantor-Bernstein theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) is most commonly proved using an argument that involves the integers. In fact, there is a [simple proof](http://chiasme.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/a-short-proof-of-cantor-bernstein-schroeder-theorem/) based on an elementary fixed point lemma.

Answer (score 2):

The [uniform boundedness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle) states that the pointwise boundedness of a collection of continuous linear operators on a Banach space implies uniform boundedness (with respect to the operator norm).

While the most preferred modern proof—relying on [Baire's category theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem)—is simple and elegant, there is actually an older proof based on a more transparent, more elementary, but also more tedious inductive argument.

Namely, if a collection of continuous linear operators fails to be bounded with respect to the operator norm, then one can find a point at which pointwise boundedness fails, too. The proof involves constructing a sequence of operators that exhibit ever larger values at certain points, and then “pushing” these outliers to infinity to obtain a point at which pointwise boundedness breaks down. Accordingly, this older proof is coined the technique of the “gliding hump.” See [Megginson (1998, p. 49)](http://books.google.com/books?id=fD-GeCsqoqkC&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=gliding+hump&source=bl&ots=qu390edYst&sig=eItjJMGcEKK2y-LPj7OJH7MrsUI&hl=hu&sa=X&ei=H8VuVIOlGYb1yATw34LABw&ved=0CG4Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=gliding%20hump&f=false) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The proof in
N.S Mendelsohn, An application of a famous inequality, Amer. Math. Monthly 58
(1951), 563
that
$(1+1/n)^n
\to e$

which uses the arithmetic-geometric mean
inequality (AGMI),
 which we will use in the
form 
$((v_1+v_2+...v_n)/n)^n > v_1v_2...v_n$
 (all $v_i$ positive) 
with equality if and only if all the $v_i$ are
equal.

Consider $n$ values of $1+1/n$
and $1$ value of $1$. 
By the AGMI, 
$((n+2)/(n+1))^{n+1} > (1+1/n)^n
$, or 
$(1+1/(n+1))^{n+1} > (1+1/n)^n$.

Consider $n$ values of $1-1/n$
 and $1$ value of $1$. 
By the AGMI,
$(n/(n+1))^{n+1} > (1-1/n)^n$
 or
 $(1+1/n)^{n+1} < (1+1/(n-1))^n
$.

Therefore
$(1+1/n)^n$
is increasing
and
$(1+1/n)^{n+1}$
is decreasing.

Since
$0
< (1+1/n)^{n+1}-(1+1/n)^n
= (1+1/n)^{n}/n
<4/n
$,
the two sequences converges to
a common limit.

To show that
$(1+1/n)^{n}
< 4
$,
note that
$(1+1/n)^{n}
<(1+1/n)^{n+1}
\le 2^2
$
 (with 
$n=1)
=4
$,

Answer (score 1):

**Pythagorean Theorem**

When i was in school, I struggled hard to understand and remember the proof of Pythagorean Theorem. But when i came across the below proof I was surprised a lot. ( How simple it is!!!)

Let's say a triangle has three sides a, b, c. Take four such triangles.

[image]

Three of these have been rotated 90°, 180°, and 270°, respectively. Each has area ab/2. Let's put them together without additional rotations so that they form a square with side c.

[image]

The square has a square hole with the side (a - b). Summing up its area (a - b)² and 2ab, the area of the four triangles (4·ab/2), we get

c²  = (a - b)² + 4.ab/2
    = a² - 2ab + b² + 2ab
    = a² + b²

Here is an animation of the same proof from wikipedia:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recall the Quadratic Reciprocity Law which states that for $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ prime with $p \neq q$: 
$$ \left(\frac{p}{q}\right) \left(\frac{q}{p}\right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2} \frac{q-1}{2}}.$$
Where $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)$ is the Legendre symbol of $p$ with respect to $q$.

When I was first shown this theorem it was proved with Eisentein's method. But this law has a lot of proofs. Here is [a list of 246 proofs](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/rchrono.html) of the Quadratic Reciprocity Law, hosted by the University of Heidelburg. Notably, both Gauss and Kronecker each have 8 different proofs.

Answer (score 0):

Brahmagupta's Formula which finds the area for a cyclic quadrilateral based on side lengths.

The formula is shown below where K is the area and $a, b, c$, and $d$ are the side lengths.

$$K=\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{(-a+b+c+d)(a-b+c+d)(a+b-c+d)(a+b+c-d)}$$

Here is a [proof](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/Brahmagupta.shtml) of the formula.